# Android web view "back" button to load previously loaded div

Tags: android, jquery, webview, back

I will try to explain this as clearly as possible. I have an android app using web view to basically load a webpage as my app. I have everything working great, however the back button seems to be an issue. I have set this page up all on one html page, it will load in a div when certain buttons are clicked to give the feel of a new page without actually having one. I basically want the back button (on the android tablet or smartphone) to load the previously loaded div, but I have no idea where to start with this. Here is what the content switching jquery looks like -

function contentSwitcher(settings){
        var settings = {
           contentClass : '.contentToLoad',
           navigationId : '#sideMenu',
           servFront : '#clickHomeHome'

```
   };
     //Hide all of the content except the first one on the nav
    $(settings.contentClass).not(':first').hide();
    $(settings.navigationId).find('li:first').addClass('active');

    //onClick set the active state, 
    //hide the content panels and show the correct one
    $(settings.navigationId).find('a').click(function(e){
        var contentToShow = $(this).attr('href');
        contentToShow = $(contentToShow);
        //dissable normal link behaviour
        e.preventDefault();
        //set the proper active class for active state css
        $(settings.navigationId).find('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        //hide the old content and show the new
        $(settings.contentClass).hide();
        contentToShow.show("slow");
     });
}
```

contentSwitcher();
});

note: I've cropped out a bunch of it just to show how it works on a basic level.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where to begin. I'd just like the back button function to be able to maybe check a started previous div name stored somewhere and load that.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the History API. There are numerous tutorials on the web e.g. this one is quite good:

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Basically this is how it works. When the user clicks the link for the div to show you push the state to the history stack.

```
 history.pushState({<object with any information about state>}, pageTitle, newUrl);
```

This will push the state to the history stack meaning that when the user presses the back button on any modern browser like webkit it will take that state into consideration. When back action is taken it will then pop the state from the history stack. This action you have to listen to and handle in any way you see fit:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
    // event object contains the information from the pushed state
    // do whatever needed to load the previous page here
});
```

The History API requires you to structure your code in a certain way for it to work well. For this I would recommend to use some existing framework that handle the back events for you e.g. Backbone.js. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for sharing. Will this work if applied to the back function of - say an android tablet or smartphone. Right now it just exits out of my app, but I'd like it to tie into something just like this.

Comment: This should work for android phone back buttons, at least the ones I tried.

Comment: This is awesome, I didn't even know about this API until now, very interesting stuff! My question is - the url of my webview page never changes, it just swaps in (and out) a new div to give the illusion of new pages, would I be able to apply this to the divs changing? I'm just curious because the url never actually changes. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: This solution implies that you have to have to different urls for the different states of the app. Using the history API does not reload anything when changing URLs if that is what you are worried about?

Comment: So, I would have to associate each div with a url? So something along the lines of - when I call to .show the content div in the jquery, I could also tag it with a url using the push state? Then use that url to track the history? Is this correct?